# I can't see my image attachments (even url) when i export a list from sharepoint to excel

Tags: excel, export, image

I have been trying to export a sharepoint list. The list has a column with image attachment, ( the images were loaded from powerapps linked to that particular sharepoint list). The issue is that when I export the list I cant find the attachment column in the excel doc, not even the image url. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior for exporting a list to excel when there are attachments to the items.  Attachments are not included in the excel output.